# Unable to store quartz .net job

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz.net

```
 +$exception    {Quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store job: Type  
'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' in Assembly 
'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable. ---> 
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 
'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' in Assembly 
'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF serialization problem using NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939118/wcf-serialization-problem-using-namevaluecollection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by .NET Core incompatibility for serialization, please switch to using JSON serialization as described in this [issue](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/661). - [@lahma](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/672#issuecomment-418023962).
Hope this helps others.